# How can I exit from mysql_secure_installation?

Tags: mysql, terminal, command-line-interface, ubuntu-20.04

[Screenshot of the installation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eXS9.jpg)

As you can see at the image (link above) I started an installation of mysql by typing

> mysql_secure_installation

on the **Ubuntu 20.04 terminal**.

But now I just want to cancel (exit) the installation. The process is now in the password setting section (like in the image above).

I tried ctrl+x, ctrl+q, ctrl+d, ESC but none of them worked.

Should I just close the terminal window? (I want that nothing will be saved of the process)

I'm waiting for your help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 34):

## The Solution

From another terminal:

```
sudo kill $(ps aux | grep mysql_secure_installation | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')
```

Per qt-x's comment, if your system supports pgrep you can use:

```
sudo kill $(pgrep mysql_secure_installation)
```

You can then run 'mysql_secure_installation' again.   But you may want to read the "Why I Know This" section below first....., which may explain why you have to exit 'mysql_secure_installation' in the first place [for some people].

## Why I Know This

For some reason, recently I've had to set my root password first before running this script:

```
> mysql
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'mynewpassword';
```

Or I end up in an endless loop where I can't set the password, and the message is:

```
Failed! Error: SET PASSWORD has no significance for user ‘root’@’localhost’ as the authentication method used doesn’t store authentication data in the MySQL server
```

Comment: Shortcut for stoping the loop:  sudo kill $(pgrep mysql_secure_installation)

Comment: Thank you for the "Why I Know This" bit, this was the solution after an hour of searching -- changing the root password prior to starting my_secure_installation!

Comment: However, this does not work as all efforts to connect to the server via ssh from another terminal failed

Comment: @EmmanuelDavid - yeah but that is going to be a separate and unrelated issue.

Answer (score 16):

ctrl+c will work, but only at the following position:

> Do you wish to continue with the password provided?(Press y|Y for Yes,
> any other key for No) :

Comment: Works for me. The reason why it is not working on `New Password:` and `Re-enter new password:` is because it reads ^C like a character

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me and was useful since I was ssh'd into the machine and didn't want to have to open yet another terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a simpler command to kill mysql_secure_installation

```
sudo pkill -f mysql_secure_installation
```

`pgrep -af mysql_secure_installation` to get the current state.

Answer (score -5):

very easy, just type ctrl+c
it worked for me, don't know about you